# Checking up on a link exchange

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have made a link exchange with another site. 3 days later, the site has removed my link.

Is there a simple php script to help me control link exchanges and notify me if my link has been removed?

I need it as simple as possible, and not a whole ad. system manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the URL of webpage where your ad(link) exists then you can use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get all links of that webpage in array and then use php [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check that your link exists in that array or not. You can run this script on daily bases using [crontab](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

```
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

// Find all links 
$allLinks = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $allLinks[] =  $element->href;
}

// Check your link. 
$adLink = "http://www.mylink.com";
if ( in_array($adLink , $allLinks ) ) {
    echo "My link exists.";
} else {
    echo "My link is removed.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically there's no way to know if someone's website has a link to yours unless you have traffic directed from their website or you look at their website.

Your best bet would be either:

A script which records every time they link to your image. This is simple enough by mixing PHP and .htaccess

```
.htaccess:

RewriteRule path/to/myImage.jpg path/to/myScript.php

myScript.php:

/* Record (database, file, or however) that they accessed */
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents("path/to/myImage.jpg");
```

Or a script which looks at their website every X amount of minutes/hours/days and searches the returned HTML for the link to your image. The challenge here is making the script run periodically. This can be done with crontab or similar

```
myScript.php:

$html = file_get_contents("http://www.theirsite.com");
if(strpos($html, 'path/to/myImage.jpg') !== FALSE)
    /* Happiness */
else
    /* ALERT! */
```